# How to insert a caption under images which inserted top of Hero Image

Tags: html, css

I've inserted some images top of hero image and I want add caption like this

[image: Expected Result]

But the code I've applied isn't apply the way I think. The text I want to apply display under the hero image instead of thumbnail image.

[image: Actual Result]

I even try figure and figcaption. Nothing worked. Here is my code.

```css
    img{
        height: 50%;
      background-position: center;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: cover;
      position: relative;
      opacity: 25;
    }
    
    .carousel-caption {
        text-align: left;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 30%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      color: white;
    }
    
    .over-img{
      position: absolute;
      top: 65%;
      left: 6.5%;
      width : 85px;
      height: 85px;
    }
    
    div.caption {
      float: left;
      clear: both;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <img src="assets/img/Home-hero.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                      <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="padding-left:50px;">
                            <h1 style="font-size: 75px; font-weight: 700;">We Fix<br> What Matters</h1><br>
                            <p>We use edge technology to deliver high quality and<br> proffessional restoration services</p>
                          </div>
                        
                          <div class="pic">
                          <img src="assets/img/home/Water.png" class="over-img">
                          <div class="caption">Water</div>
                         </div>
   

    </div>
                </div>
              </div>
```

Comment: I have created HTML snippets for your reference. Hope it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this live [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/fgyajmor/2/). This works for you.

Here you have structured layout and positioned elements incorrectly.

```css
img{
  height: 50%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 25;
}

.carousel-item {
  position: relative;
}

.carousel-caption {
  text-align: left;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 30%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
}

.over-img{
  /* position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 6.5%; */
  width : 85px;
  height: 85px;
}

.pic-sec {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 999;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.pic {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.caption {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div id="carouselExampleSlidesOnly" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <div class="carousel-inner">
              <div class="carousel-item active">
                  <img src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/YGE5euSZnbI/maxresdefault.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
                  <div class="carousel-caption d-none d-md-block" style="padding-left:50px;">
                        <h1 style="font-size: 75px; font-weight: 700;">We Fix<br> What Matters</h1><br>
                        <p>We use edge technology to deliver high quality and<br> proffessional restoration services</p>
                      </div>

                      <div class="pic-sec">
                        <div class="pic">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="over-img">
                        <div class="caption">Water</div>
                       </div>
                       
                       <div class="pic">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="over-img">
                        <div class="caption">Water</div>
                       </div>
                       
                       <div class="pic">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="over-img">
                        <div class="caption">Water</div>
                       </div>
                       
                       <div class="pic">
                        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" class="over-img">
                        <div class="caption">Water</div>
                       </div>

                      </div>
                        
               </div>

            </div>

          </div>
```

Comment: Hi VSM. It worked fine. currently looking a way to position those to bottom left. Thank you very much for your kind support!!!!

Comment: You need align pic section to bottom left?

Comment: @SamionLine It's my pleasure. If my answer is helpful. Please mark it as the correct answer and upvote it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Without testing class pic needs to be inline block and image should be displayed block.

Comment: Hi any idea on applying caption under the thumbails since inline-block makes my thumbnails disappear.